# input size depending on input

Tags: c++

If it makes sense.

This is how it looks so far.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char *buffer;
    buffer = new char[100];

    std::cin >> buffer;

    const int size = strlen(buffer);

    char input[size];

    delete buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

I know I can use the string library but I'm trying to do without it.

I want to make the char size (in the code char input) depending on the input size.

The errors which I am getting is

```
expression did not evaluate to a constant
expression must have a constant value
```

on line 12 which is the

```
char input[size];
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific as to what your problem or question is?

Comment: C++ has a built in answer for you: [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: Is there an issue that you're coming across? if so please detail. @NathanOliver he is trying not to use `std::string`.

Comment: I'm getting the error
expression did not evaluate to a constant
On line 12 which is char input[size];

Comment: @ChrisK what type of input are you expecting in the `buffer` array?

Comment: Don't try to not use `string`.

Comment: @m_callends normal text

Comment: "I'm trying to do without it." You have to tell us why, otherwise there's little point to the question.

Comment: It may sound funny but...
I'm trying to make an alternative to the string library, but it's for practicing reasons.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is the length of used space in the buffer array you are trying to assign to `size` for the `input` array, there are two methods you can use...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char *buffer = new char[100];

  cin >> buffer;

  int spaceUsed = 0;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    if (buffer[i] != '\0')
      spaceUsed++;
  }

  char input[spaceUsed];
  delete [] buffer;

  return 0;
}
```

OR...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char *buffer = new char[100];

  cin >> buffer;

  int spaceUsed = 0;

  while (*buffer++)
      spaceUsed++;

  char input[spaceUsed];
  delete [] buffer;

  return 0;
}
```

Both code snippets do the exact same thing. Of course, using the `string` library would make your life much easier though.

Comment: That is not valid C++ code. You cannot use `char input[spaceUsed];` unless `spaceUsed` is known at compile time.

Comment: You are most likely using a non-standard functionality in your compiler.

Comment: Im running on my university's student servers for compilation and programming with the G++ compiler.

Comment: For me, it's giving the same errors as on my code. I'm using VS.

Comment: If you use `-pedantic` as a command line option, you will see the compiler warning: *warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘input’ [-Wvla]*

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can use the string library but I'm trying to do without it.

You can use `std::vector<char>`. If that is not an option either, allocate memory yourself and make sure that you deallocate the memory.

```
char* input = new char[size+1];  // Add an extra for the terminating null characterr

....


delete [] input;
```

Answer (score 0):

For `std::cin` you need to pre-allocate a buffer. If you plan on using `char[]` and you really have to avoid strings you have to make sure you allocate enough memory.

Alternatively you can read char by char with `scanf("%c",&newChar)` until user inputs an escape character and allocate memory for array as you go.
I don't suppose you're limited to using `iostream` ?